# How to pronounce these words "rendered", "tired","hired"...?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I know that 'render' is pronounced /'ren-dər/. But, with the /d/ sound added (/'ren-dərd/), does it sound exactly the same on the vowel part in the second syllable of 'mustard' and 'bastard'. And; 'tired', 'hired', do they also sound the same in the second syllable? (/'tai-ərd/)

Thanks.

Comment: Pronunciation can be found in the dictionary.  However please understand that the sound of any word still varies widely between English dialects.  For example, in AmE we would pronounce both the "r" and the "d" sounds in all of your given words; however in BrE (and AusE) they (more or less) just extend the vowel sound, drop the "r", and pronounce the "d" ("rendahd", "bastahd", "mustahd").

Comment: Well, AmE except for South Boston, which also doesn't pronounce final "r" sounds, "I paaked the caa in the garaage".

Comment: The dictionary doesn't answer everything. Because; sometimes, i heard people said the word 'scared' , it sounds like /sker/ with no /d/. I'm confused that's why I asked. If I could find the answer in a dictionary( merriam-webster, oxford,...), i wouldn't take time to ask a question.

Comment: I'm not sure that is fair. The dictionary gives the pronunciation of words but doesn't explain why. I thought this site was suppose to be about language learning?

Comment: @domino Ordinarily English speakers will pronounce the "d" at the end of words like "scared".  Otherwise it would just be "scare", which changes the meaning.  Some dialects might use the present tense instead of the past tense, but this is not common.  Is it possible you just didn't hear the "d" sound?  I know sometimes it takes a while to train your ear to the subtleties of another language.

Comment: @Erin-KateSousa The question can be re-opened, especially if it is [edit]ed to clarify why a dictionary doesn't answer it. One way to go about getting it reopened is to bring it to the community's attention by posting about it on Meta and explaining why you think it should be reopened. Here is an example : http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/3411/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word stress is on the first syllable in your examples words. This influences the pronunciation because an unaccented (or weak) vowel is pronounced as the schwa sound. The schwa sound is a reduction of all possible vowels. So in your example all the words are stressed in the first syllable and we hear the distinct difference of vowels in the beginning of the word- rEnder and mUstard. But the final syllables sound the same- schwa sound. 
*I am sure you can find some You Tube videos if you search schwa sound or pronunciation. I like Rachel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BmkUa4Mv60

Comment: This site is about language learning, but at the same time it's considered a language resource that shows up first in Google results.  So we strive for accurate and complete information.   It also helps if you add links to additional, supporting resources wherever possible -- for example, you say it should be "easy" to find a YouTube video showing pronunciation, so it would have been better if you linked to one that gives a clear example of your advice.